# Azure service bus topic/subscriptions being deleted

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-topics

I have at topic/subscription that is being deleted nightly.  Using Service Bus Explorer I have set the Days value of "Auto Delete On Idle" to multiple days (for example 5).  But overnight it is still being deleted.  Has anyone had this issue before?

I would assume that setting the  "Auto Delete On Idle" to multiple days (for example 5) would keep the topic/subscription from being deleted for that amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is bit strange one. Make sure no other automated code deletes the subscription.

Setting AutoDeleteOnIdle will make sure the subscription is deleted if no client tries to read or write to the subscription for the given timespan idle interval.